# Calculate Values per Row - Android, SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, row

I would like to see if I can get a sample method written in Android that would achieve the following:

Loop through each row in a SQLlite table; grab the sum of all numbers;
to keep simple, lets say there are 3 columns with a numeric value in each row, and a forth that is simply the "row id" that should not be included.

(Let's assume the table has been created and everything is set-up; just looking for the method that would do this.  Lets sat the method outputs the number to a TextView on the activity that calls it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope, you have basic knowledge and you can operate with `Cursor`.

1. Get `Cursor` with your data
2. Enumerate through each row
3. Enumerate through each columns
4. Calculate SUM
5. Set result to `TextView`

   ```
   long sum = 0;
   Cursor cursor = db.query(...); // or contentResolver.query(...)
   for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
       int columns = cursor.getColumnCount();
       for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
           sum += cursor.getLong(col); // or cursor.getInt(col)
       }
   }
   cursor.close();

   textView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I do understand Cursor basics.  Quick question: In the above example, what query would you write for this where you typed "..."?

Comment: If you need all records and all columns, just call db.query("my_table", null, null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: BTW, you can get SUM everything right in the query: cursor = db.rawQuery("select sum(col1) + sum(col2) + sum(col3) as total_sum from my_table", null); long sum = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("total_sum"));

Comment: I just saw that I may have mistyped the question: what if you want to get the sum of each row, store it in a variable (I assume an array), and move on to next row.  So lets say you have ten rows, you would need to store ten different variables.  That is what I SHOULD have asked in the beginning... though your answer got me on the right track...